# Who was Takshak snake?

Tags: mahabharata, krishna, bhagavata-purana, arjuna

In the Mahabharat,there was a snake and he was also a friend of Lord Indra and he was defeated in the Mahabharata war and his name was "Takshak". So,who is he and what is his story?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [Mahabharata](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m01/m01036.htm) and [Shrimad Bhagavatam](http://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/5/24/29), Takshaka was a son of Kadru and Kashyapa Maharshi.

The story of Takshaka is mentioned in [Shrimad Bhagavatam](http://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/12/6). It goes like below:

> Parīkṣit, who was the grandson of Arjuna, having listened to
>   the Bhāgavatam, had attained the transcendental position of
>   fearlessness and oneness with the Supreme. Thus, Parīkṣit, free of all
>   doubts, sat down in yogic posture and merged himself in meditation
>   upon the Supersoul.
>
> Then the snake-bird **Takṣaka**, arriving in the disguise of a brāhmaṇa,
>   bit him, and the body of the saintly king immediately burned to ashes.

This means, Takṣaka was responsible for slaying Parīkṣit. 
Actually, Parīkṣit himself was [cursed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parikshit#Death) by a sage's son to die by a snake bite. Takshaka came to fulfil the curse. Takshaka did the deed by approaching in disguise.

Later King Janamejaya, the son of Parikshit, become [angry](http://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/12/6) and  fought a war with nagas.

> Janamejaya, the son of Parīkṣit, became very angry when he received
>   news of his father’s death, and he began a sacrificial performance for
>   the purpose of destroying all the snakes.
>
> Even though Takṣaka received protection from Indra, he nevertheless
>   became attracted by the mantras and was about to fall into the fire.
>   Seeing this, Bṛhaspati, the son of Aṅgirā Ṛṣi, came and advised
>   Janamejaya that Takṣaka could not be killed because he had drunk the
>   nectar of the demigods.

Janamejaya was thus convinced by the words of Bṛhaspati and stopped his sacrifice.

Takshaka later became a [robber](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Takshaka), waiting to loot anything valuable from the travellers traversing through his domain.

Later, when Janamejaya started a campaign with the view of [exterminating](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Takshaka#Revenge_on_Pandavas) the Naga race Takshaka left his territory and escaped to the Deva territory where he sought protection from Deva king Indra.

But Janamejaya's men traced him and brought him as a prisoner, to execute him along with the other Naga chiefs. At that time, a learned sage named Astika, a boy in age, came and interfered. Janamejaya had to listen to the words of the learned Astika and set Takshaka free.  From then onwards the Nagas and Kurus lived in peace.

Comment: The Takshaka of Ikshvaku Vamsa was different from Takshaka the snake.  He was a son of Kadru and Kashyapa Maharshi.

Comment: See [this reference](http://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/5/24/29)

Comment: Takshaka belonging to Ikshvaku  is also mentioned in Wikipedia and also in Shrimad Bhagavatam. I mentioned links for both the sources in my post.

Comment: People have same names. The Naga Takshaka was different from Ikshvaku king Takshaka. See the reference I posted from Bhagavatam. Also Wikipedia is not a reliable source.

Comment: I guess better you may post your own answer with what you think are correct and reliable sources. You are also welcome to edit my post with appropriate details. I searched and found ref. which I posted in Answer. Please feel free to correct them if you think so.

Comment: I would have posted an answer but except for the Ikshvaku fact your answer is right. I'll try to edit it. :)

Comment: This is the link to Shrimad Bhagavatam  where  Takshaka is mentioned belonged to the Ikshvaku dynasty. http://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/9/12

Comment: I have edited your answer. Please check it. Also as far as I know they were two different Takshakas.

Comment: Surya is right, the Naga Takshaka and the Takshaka who belonged to the Ikshvaku dynasty have nothing to do with each other.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan I updated post with Surya's input/ref. I guess root cause of confusion was this Wiki link  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Takshaka#Family which clearly stated that Takshaka belonged to the Ikshvaku dynasty. He was a descendent of Shri Rama.

Comment: @AADTechnical Yeah, Wikipedia is mixing up the two Takshakas.

Comment: Need website references.